# ScrollController not attached to any scroll views

Tags: flutter

I'm using CustomScrollView, and providing it with a controller.
ScrollController works, I even added a listener to it and print out the position of the scroll view.

```
CustomScrollView(
    controller: _scrollController,
```

Now, all i'm trying to do is jump to position 50.0 inside initState() function.

```
_scrollController.jumpTo(50.0);
```

But, i get the error

> scrollController not attached to any scroll views

Comment: Please post more code. Where are you calling `jumpTo`? You are not allowed to do it in `initState` or similar methods.

Comment: @boformer yes, as i mentioned in my question, i'm calling it inside initState, the documentation doesn't mention anything about not calling it inside initState.

Comment: I also tried that. It doesn't work because the controller is only attached once the `build` method was run and the scroll view is attached to the tree.

Answer (score 155, accepted):

Check if the scrollController is attached to a scroll view by using its hasClients property first.

```
if (_scrollController.hasClients) 
    _scrollController.jumpTo(50.0);
```

Comment: My mistake was that I attached the controller to `Scrollbar` instead of `SingleChildScrollView` `child: Scrollbar( child: SingleChildScrollView( controller: _scrollController,` . I thought I should share in case any of you might have a similar situation.

Comment: how do you get the listview.builder to always show the scrollbar

Comment: This only works it it is inside the WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback() as answeredd by @carlosx2

Answer (score 71):

Delaying it is not the right solution. Better to wait till the tree is done building by using

```
WidgetsBinding.instance
        .addPostFrameCallback((_){});
```

**sample**

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      if(pageController.hasClients){
              pageController.animateToPage(page index, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1), curve: Curves.easeInOut);
      }
});
```

Comment: the page didn't move the index page after add the **Callback** function. i have removed the call back function and add the `if(pageController.hasClients){
              pageController.animateToPage(page index, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1), curve: Curves.easeInOut);
      }` its working now.

Comment: best solution for this case, thanks a lot

Answer (score 28):

To set the initial position of a `ScrollController`, use the `initialScrollOffset` property:

```
_scrollController = ScrollController(initialScrollOffset: 50.0);
```

Comment: better solution is suggested below. First check if it is attached or not by `if(_scrollController.hasClients)` then you should call `jumpTo` or `animateTo`. On android it still works if you skip client checking .. but on IOS it will cause problem.

Comment: I dont see it causing problems in IOS (at least in 14) and Flutter 2.5.
Unless you add a Scrollbar() as a parent - for me, that caused the exception in IOS.

Comment: I am using ListView instead ScrollView, none of above answers helped me.  `_scrollController.hasClients` never triggered  when I used it in `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback` 

But this works. Thanks.

Comment: For those who doesn't even call _scrollController's `jumpTo` or `animateTo`, the complier still spills out `ScrollController not attached to any scroll views` issue.Then should try  to provide  a `initialScrollOffset ` value when initialize `ScrollController `.

Answer (score 13):

@carlosx2 answer is correct but if someone wonder where to put WigetsBinding. So here it is.

```
@override
void initState(){
  super.initState();
  WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_){
    //write or call your logic
    //code will run when widget rendering complete
  });
}
```

Comment: In Dart 2.12 instance can be null. "The method 'addPostFrameCallback' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'. "

Comment: Use the unconditional call operator like so: `WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback`

Answer (score 10):

I resolved my problem using the same ScrollController to both controllers.
First I create the ScrollController():

```
ScrollController scollBarController = ScrollController();
```

Inside my code:

```
Container(
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
    child: Scrollbar(
      controller: scollBarController,
      isAlwaysShown: true,
      child: StaggeredGridView.count(
        controller: scollBarController,
        crossAxisCount: 16,
        staggeredTiles: _staggeredTamanho,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        children: [
          ...
        ], //listStaggered,
        mainAxisSpacing: 7.0,
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

Comment: Not working for me. Scrollbar(
        isAlwaysShown: true,
        controller: controller,
        child: ListView(
          controller: controller,

Answer (score 5):

Initialize the scrollController:

```
ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();
```

Use the code bellow where you want to scroll:

```
SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
  _scrollController.jumpTo(_scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

This **sometimes** happens when you are attempting to bind a ScrollController to a widget that doesn't actually exist (yet). So it attempts to bind, but there is no ListView/ScrollView to bind to. 
Say you have this code:

```
Column(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
  children: <Widget>[
    Expanded(
      flex: 8,
      child: Container(
        child: ListView.builder(
          controller: scrollController,
          itemCount: messages.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return MessageTile(message: messages[index]);
          }),
        ),
     ),
 ]),
```

Here we are building a ListView dynamically. Since we never declared this ListView before, the scrollController does not have anything to bind to. But this can easily be fixed:

// first declare the ListView and ScrollController

```
final scrollController = ScrollController(initialScrollOffset: 0);
ListView list = ListView.builder(
  controller: scrollController,
  itemCount: messages.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return MessageTile(message: messages[index]);
  }
);
```

// then inside your build function just reference the already built list

```
Column(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
  children: <Widget>[
    Expanded(
      flex: 8,
      child: Container(
         child: list,
      ),
    ),
  ]),
```

Answer (score 3):

I have tried with above solutions but set ScrollController initialScrollOffset, checking hasClients and jumpTo, WidgetsBinding no one is working for me.

at last solved my problem by checking positions 'scrollcontroller.positions.length' like

```
if (_sc.positions.length == 0 || _sc.position.pixels == 0.0) {
    return Container();
}
```

**You have to check controller positions to get rid of the error**

Reference : https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollController/position.html

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue when using a ListView with a ScrollBar. The solution was to explicitly set the same controller to both the ScrollBar and ListView

```
final ScrollController _controller = ScrollController();

CupertinoScrollbar(
  controller: _controller,
  child: ListView.builder(
    controller: _controller,
```

Comment: returns Error "ScrollController attached to multiple scroll views" in my case.

Answer (score 2):

I solving using the same controller in Scrollbar() e ListView() widgets.

```
Container(
    height: 140,
    child: Scrollbar(
        controller: listviewScrollbarController,
        child: ListView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            controller: listviewScrollbarController,
            children: [
                // ....
            ]
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a ListView, GridView, or any other scrollable widget, you need to create a ScrollController and pass it to the controller parameter of the Scrollbar widget:

```
  final _scrollController = ScrollController();
  Scrollbar(
    controller: _scrollController,
     child: ListView(
     controller: _scrollController, // also pass to the scrollable widget

     ),
  );
```

It's means,the listView needs its parent component and its own life controller.

Answer (score 0):

I found working solution, but frankly the method is not best practice, I suppose. 
In my case **controller.jumpTo()** was called before it was attached to any scroll view. In order to solve problem I delayed some milliseconds and then call .jumpTo(), because build will be called and controller will be attached to any scroll view.

```
Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: <some time, ex: 100>), () {
         _scrollController.jumpTo(50.0);
        });
```

I full agree that it is bad solution, but It can solve problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use setState() method to bind to a scroll related widget (your listview etc.)

```
setState(() {
    topicsScrollController.animateTo(....);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this code to make the color of the appbar transparent at 0 position and black for more than 70

```
backgroundColor: !_scrollController.hasClients
            ? Colors.transparent
            : _scrollController.offset > 70
                ? Color.fromRGBO(7, 7, 7, 1)
                : Colors.transparent,
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, but in my case was much simpler, althought I think it worth mention:

Don't **forget to attach the controller to your widget**. In my case I rearrange my screens and change the PageView. No widgets bindings would fix it because it was not point to any!

Answer (score 0):

Declare an object of controller like this.

```
 final _scrollController = ScrollController();
```

And then provide it to both, to Scrollbar and to it child (ListView in this case)

```
Scrollbar(
       thumbVisibility: true,
       controller: _scrollController,
       child: ListView(
              controller: _scrollController,
              children: [
                         Text("Hello World"),
                         Text("Hello World"),
                         Text("Hello World"),
                   ],
              ),
```

Answer (score 0):

**Define a scroll conotroller;**

```
final _scrollController = ScrollController();
```

**Assign it to both controllers**

```
Scrollbar(
 controller: _scrollController,
 child: ListView(
    controller: _scrollController,
    itemBuilder: ...
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `ListView.builder` inside `ListView` and attaching controller to `ListView.builder`, it will work only if you have `ListView.builder`.

Answer (score 0):

## How To Fix At Web Platfrom

### error:

```
The Scrollbar attempted to use the PrimaryScrollController. This ScrollController should be associated with the ScrollView that the Scrollbar is being applied to.A ScrollView with an Axis.vertical ScrollDirection on mobile platforms will automatically use the PrimaryScrollController if the user has not provided a ScrollController. To use the PrimaryScrollController explicitly, set ScrollView.primary to true for the Scrollable widget.
```

### fixed

avoid use "Scrollbar" at web platform, while working fine in Mobile platfrom :

```
Scrollbar(
        child: scrollChild,
        isAlwaysShown: true,
      )
```