# ScrollController attached to multiple scroll views, while navigating to another page

Tags: listview, flutter, dart

I want to navigate to the next page after reaching the bottom of a ListView, When I navigate the first time is works, but when I try it again it fails with this error :

```
ScrollController attached to multiple scroll views.
Failed assertion: line 111 pos 12: '_positions.length == 1'
```

I have read a couple of posts e.g [post1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52114535/scrollcontroller-not-attached-to-any-scroll-views), but couldn't get a workaround.

This is my implementation :

```
double previousScrollOffset = 0.0;

  ScrollController _controller;
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();



    _controller = ScrollController( initialScrollOffset: previousScrollOffset);

    _controller.addListener(() {

        if (_controller.position.atEdge) {
          if (_controller.position.pixels == 0) {
            // you are at the top
            print('You are at the top');
          } else {
            //bottom
//            previousScrollOffset = _controller.offset;
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => CustomSwipeDownPage()),
            );
          }
        }

    });
  }
```

Then, this is how I call it inside the `ListView` :

```
ListView(controller: _controller)
```

What is the solution ?

Comment: Thats may not be because of the `ScrollController`, Another error on the widget tree may cause this issue.

Comment: @Blasanka, thanks for the concern, actually I got it work by shifting the `List<Widget> pageList = List<Widget>();`, to the `build` method. This was my initial code :https://gist.github.com/huxaiphaer/553bfd68f8a60b9e876599d96bc83a1e

Comment: I couldnt see any errors in the provided gist. I think issue inside `Material()` in the `firstPage()`. Or inside your `if (_controller.position.atEdge) {` navigation to other page

Comment: No, the issue was my `List<Widget> pageList = List<Widget>();` declaration in state , it was duplicated for the first time I navigated, thus causing the error.

I have solved it.