# Flutter The Scrollbar's ScrollController has no ScrollPosition attached

Tags: flutter, dart, scrollview, scrollbar, singlechildscrollview

I get this `error` when using the `AppBar`:

> The Scrollbar's ScrollController has no ScrollPosition attached.

This is my `CustomScrollBar`:

```
class CustomScrollBar extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final ScrollController scrollController;

  const CustomScrollBar({
    required this.scrollController,
    required this.child,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RawScrollbar(
      thumbColor: AppColors.gray,
      radius: Radius.circular(8),
      thickness: 4,
      isAlwaysShown: true,
      controller: scrollController,
      child: child,
    );
  }
}
```

I should be always visible. And this is how I use it:

```
child: CustomScrollBar(
              scrollController: _scrollControllerForScrollBar,
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                controller: _scrollControllerForScrollBar,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(7.0.scaled),
                  child: Container(
                    width: double.infinity,
                    child: Text(
                      'any text bla bla bla \n\n\n this is a lot of \n text \n .'
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

As you can see both the `ScrollBar` and the `SingleChildScrollView` use the same `ScrollController`. I have no idea why this error occurs. Any idea what I am missing here?

Comment: In your CustomScrollBar, you need to assign the scrollController to RawScrollBar.

Comment: @SamiIssa Ah I missed that in the question, in my code it is attached

Comment: Here is some work around https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52114535/scrollcontroller-not-attached-to-any-scroll-views

Answer (score 90, accepted):

I was using a `ScrollBar` with a `ListView` widget and was getting this error in the debug console.  To get rid of it, I had to set the `ScrollController` on both widgets.

```
final yourScrollController = ScrollController();

Scrollbar(
  isAlwaysShown: true,
  thickness: 10,
  controller: yourScrollController, // Here 
  child: ListView.builder(
    padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
    controller: yourScrollController, // AND Here
    itemCount: yourRecordList?.length
    ....
  )
)
```

Comment: This also works if your child is `SingleChildScrollView` instead of `ListView.builder`.

Answer (score 12):

Let's assume you're using both `Scrollbar` widget and `ListView` widget as a child of the scrollbar - Both of them should have the same controller as :

```
ScrollController _controller = ScrollController();

     Scrollbar(
              controller: _controller,
              child: ListView(
                controller: _controller,
           ....), // ListView
    ) // Scrollbar
```

Answer (score 3):

If you use nested scroller like this:

```
 Expanded(
                          flex: 2,
                          child: Center(
                            child: Scrollbar(
                              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                                primary: true,
                                child: Scrollbar(
                                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                   .....)
```

You can fix the issue adding this line to first Scrollable view:

```
 primary: true
```

The UI plotter wants know start position for the scroller both on mobile and low resolutions on desktop with size:

```
MediaQuery.of(context).size.shortestSide < 600
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the scrollController entirely and that should fix the problem. that is how I fixed my code so your code should look something like this

```
class CustomScrollBar extends StatelessWidget {


 final Widget child;

  const CustomScrollBar({
    required this.child,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RawScrollbar(
      thumbColor: AppColors.gray,
      radius: Radius.circular(8),
      thickness: 4,
      isAlwaysShown: true,
      child: child,
    );
  }
}
```

and the second part should be like this

```
child: CustomScrollBar(
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(7.0.scaled),
                  child: Container(
                    width: double.infinity,
                    child: Text(
                      'any text bla bla bla \n\n\n this is a lot of \n text \n .'
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

Answer (score 0):

> The following assertion was thrown during a scheduler callback:
> The Scrollbar's ScrollController has no ScrollPosition attached
>
> A Scrollbar cannot be painted without a ScrollPosition.
>
> The Scrollbar attempted to use the provided ScrollController. This
> ScrollController should be associated with the ScrollView that the
> Scrollbar is being applied to. When providing your own
> ScrollController, ensure both the Scrollbar and the Scrollable widget
> use the same one.

This is flutter's bug, https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/82573.

It is fixed on the flutter master branch:

```
flutter channel master
flutter upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

For this error, you have to define same 1 scrollController for both ScrollBar and SingleSchildScrollView/ListView:

For example from my prj:

```
  final ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController(); //define just 1 controller
  final _currencyFormatter = NumberFormat('#,##0.00', 'vi_VN');
  final double _safeSpaceToShowToolTip = 1.4;
  final double _fixedChartHeight = 350.0;
  int _touchedIndex = -1;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scrollbar(
      controller: _scrollController, // and use it both here
      isAlwaysShown: true,
      trackVisibility: true,
      radius: Radius.circular(6.0),
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        controller: _scrollController, // AND HERE
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
        child: Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: R.dimens.mediumSpacing),
          height:
              R.dimens.getSpecificSize(_fixedChartHeight, isForHeight: true),
          width: R.dimens
              .getSpecificSize(_fixedChartHeight * 1.9, isForHeight: false),
          child: BarChart(
            _barChartData(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use same scroll controller for the whole screen, It occurs on Flutter channel stable with nested scroll widgets as flutter is unable to find the main scroll view, in flutter channel master this error does not occur, so it's an error on flutter stable but do consider before switching to flutter channel master as your project might not run on flutter channel master.
Try using

```
thumbVisibility: false,
```

instead of

```
isAlwaysShown: false,
```