# _AssertionError ('package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_controller.dart': '_positions.isNotEmpty': ScrollController not attached to any scroll views.)

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RwAC.png)

.**If use page view and then scroll to other page using bottom navigation i get this error,Anyone please Help me.**

Comment: Consider including  [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)code-snippet that will reproduce the same issue

Comment: i think that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52114535/scrollcontroller-not-attached-to-any-scroll-views) answer will help you

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ScrollController not attached to any scroll views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52114535/scrollcontroller-not-attached-to-any-scroll-views)