# How can I get red of this error: LateInitializationError: Field 'currentPage' has not been initialized

Tags: flutter, dart, initialization, sharedpreferences

I am using late int currentPage; to keep the last page the reader was in. The value of this value is read from shared perefernces through the _loadIndex() method to get the reader back to the last page he were in whenever the app is reopened.
But I keep getting this error:
LateInitializationError: Field 'currentPage' has not been initialized.
The code works fine but this run time error doesn't go.
I tried all the solutions available but I could not solve this problem:

This is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';

// main method with runapp runs the class A4Run
void main() => runApp(const TajweedQuran());

class TajweedQuran extends StatefulWidget {
  const TajweedQuran({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  TajweedQuranState createState() => TajweedQuranState();
}

class TajweedQuranState extends State<TajweedQuran> {
  late int currentPage; // = 0;
  List<int> bookmarkPages = [];
  late PageController pageViewController;
  late int currentIndex1 = 0;
  late int currentIndex2 = 0;
  late int currentIndex3 = 0;
  late int currentIndex4 = 0;
  final ScrollController _scrollController1 = ScrollController();
  final ScrollController _scrollController2 = ScrollController();
  final ScrollController _scrollController3 = ScrollController();

  List<int> hizbPages = [
    1,
    11,
    22,
    32,
    42,
    51,
    62,
    72,
    82,
    92,
    102,
    111,
    121,
    132,
    142,
    151,
    162,
    173,
    182,
    192,
    201,
    212,
    222,
    231,
    242,
    252,
    262,
    272,
    282,
    292,
    302,
    312,
    322,
    332,
    342,
    352,
    362,
    371,
    382,
    392,
    402,
    413,
    422,
    431,
    442,
    451,
    462,
    472,
    482,
    491,
    502,
    513,
    522,
    531,
    542,
    553,
    562,
    572,
    582,
    591
  ];
  List<String> soraNames = [
    'الفاتحة',
    'البقرة',
    'آل عمران',
    'النساء',
    'المائدة',
    'الأنعام',
    'الأعراف',
    'الأنفال',
    'التوبة',
    'يونس',
    'هود',
    'يوسف',
    'الرعد',
    'إبراهيم',
    'الحجر',
    'النحل',
    'الإسراء',
    'الكهف',
    'مريم',
    'طه',
    'الأبئاء',
    'الحج',
    'المؤمنون',
    'النور',
    'الفرقان',
    'الشعراء',
    'النمل',
    'القصص',
    'العنكبوت',
    'الروم',
    'لقمان',
    'السجدة',
    'الأحزاب',
    'سبأ',
    'فاطر',
    'يس',
    'الصافات',
    'ص',
    'الزمر',
    'غافر',
    'فصلت',
    'الشورى',
    'الزخرف',
    'الدخان',
    'الجاثية',
    'الأحقاف',
    'محمد',
    'الفتح',
    'الحجرات',
    'ق',
    'الذاريات',
    'الطور',
    'النجم',
    'القمر',
    'الرحمن',
    'الواقعة',
    'الحديد',
    'المجادلة',
    'الحشر',
    'الممتحنة',
    'الصف',
    'الجمعة',
    'المنافقون',
    'التغابن',
    'الطلاق',
    'التحريم',
    'الملك',
    'القلم',
    'الحاقة',
    'المعارج',
    'نوح',
    'الجن',
    'المزمل',
    'المدثر',
    'القيامة',
    'الأنسان',
    'الرسلات',
    'النبأ',
    'النازعات',
    'عبس',
    'التكوير',
    'الإنفطار والمطففين',
    'الإنشقاق',
    'البروج',
    'الطارق والأعلى',
    'الغاشية',
    'الفجر',
    'البلد',
    'الشمس والليل',
    'الضحى والشرح',
    'التين والعلق',
    'القدر والبينة',
    'الزلزلة والعاديات',
    'القارعة والتكاثر',
    'العصر والهمزة والفيل',
    'قريش والماعون والكوثر',
    'الكافرون والنصر والمسد',
    'الإخلاص والفلق والناس',
  ];
  List<int> soraPages = [
    1, //الفاتحة
    2, // البقرة
    50, // آل عمران
    77, // النساء
    106, // المائدة
    128, // الأنعام
    151, // الأعراف
    177, // الأنفال
    187, // التوبة
    208,
    221,
    235,
    249,
    255,
    262,
    267,
    282,
    293,
    305,
    312,
    322,
    332,
    342,
    350,
    359,
    367,
    377,
    385,
    396,
    404,
    411,
    415,
    418,
    428,
    434,
    440,
    446,
    453,
    458,
    467,
    477,
    483,
    489,
    496,
    499,
    502,
    507,
    511,
    515,
    518,
    520,
    523,
    526,
    528,
    531,
    534,
    537,
    542,
    545,
    549,
    551,
    553,
    554,
    556,
    558,
    560,
    562,
    564,
    566,
    568,
    570,
    572,
    574,
    575,
    577,
    578,
    580,
    582,
    583,
    585,
    586,
    587,
    589,
    590,
    591,
    592,
    593,
    594,
    595,
    596,
    597,
    598,
    599,
    600,
    601,
    602,
    603,
    604,
  ];
  List<bool> bookmarks = List.filled(604, false);

  void toggleBookmark(int index) {
    setState(() {
      bookmarks[index] = !bookmarks[index];
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _loadIndex(); //Get the latest index
    _loadBookmarks();
    debugPrint(
        'currentPage: $currentPage bookMarks: ${bookmarks[currentPage]}');
    super.initState();
    //pageViewController = PageController(initialPage: currentPage);
  }

  void _goToElement(BuildContext context, int index) {
    setState(() {
      pageViewController.jumpToPage(index);
    });
  }

  _loadIndex() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    //Retrieve the index of pageview from SharedPreferences

    //currentPage = index;
    setState(() {
      currentPage = prefs.getInt('index') ?? 0;
      pageViewController = PageController(initialPage: currentPage);
    });
    //super.initState();
  }

  _saveIndex(int index) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    //save the index of pageview
    await prefs.setInt('index', index);
  }

  _loadBookmarks() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    // fetch your string list
    List<String> mList = (prefs.getStringList('stringList') ?? []);

    //convert your string list to your original int list
    List<int> mOriginaList = mList.map((i) => int.parse(i)).toList();
    setState(() {
      bookmarkPages = mOriginaList;

    });
    //super.initState();
  }

  _saveBookmarks(List<int> bookmarkPages) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    // convert your custom list to string list
    List<String> stringsList = bookmarkPages.map((i) => i.toString()).toList();

    // store your string list in shared prefs
    await prefs.setStringList("stringList", stringsList);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    pageViewController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      localizationsDelegates: const [
        GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
      supportedLocales: const [
        Locale('ar', 'AE') //OR Other RTL locales
      ],
      theme: ThemeData(fontFamily: 'cairo'),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          centerTitle: true,
          titleTextStyle: const TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white, fontSize: 24, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          title: const Text('مصحف قالون الملون'),
          actions: [
            IconButton(
              color: Colors.red,
              iconSize: 50.0,
              icon: Icon(
                bookmarks[currentPage] ? Icons.bookmark : Icons.bookmark_border,
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                toggleBookmark(currentPage);
                bookmarkPages.clear();
                for (var i = 0; i < 604; i++) {
                  bookmarks[i] ? bookmarkPages.add(i) : '';
                }
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
          child: OrientationBuilder(builder: (context, orientation) {
            return PageView.builder(
                itemCount: 604,
                onPageChanged: onchahged,
                controller: pageViewController,
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                pageSnapping: true,
                physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                itemBuilder: (context, pagePosition) {
                  return SizedBox(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    child: orientation == Orientation.landscape
                        ? SingleChildScrollView(
                            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                            child: Image.asset(
                              'images/page_${pagePosition + 1}.jpg',
                              fit: BoxFit.fill,
                            ))
                        : Image.asset(
                            'images/page_${pagePosition + 1}.jpg',
                            fit: BoxFit.fill,
                          ),
                  );
                });
          }),
        ),
        drawer: Drawer(
          elevation: 120.0,
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: [
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 90,
                  //width: 1,
                  child: DrawerHeader(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                      color: Colors.blue,
                    ),
                    child: FittedBox(
                      fit: BoxFit.contain,
                      child: Text(
                        'انتقل إلى ...',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                ExpansionTile(
                  controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
                  childrenPadding:
                      const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 20),
                  expandedCrossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  maintainState: true,
                  title: const Text(
                    'الأحزاب',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0), //color: Colors.green),
                  ),
                  children: [
                    ListView.builder(
                      key: const PageStorageKey<String>("hizb_list"),
                      controller: _scrollController1,
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      //physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                      itemCount: hizbPages.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return ListTile(
                          title: Text(
                            style: const TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 18.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            'حزب: ${index + 1}',
                          ),
                          tileColor: currentIndex1 == hizbPages[index] - 1
                              ? Colors.deepPurple
                              : null,
                          onTap: () {
                            setState(() {
                              currentIndex1 = hizbPages[index] - 1;
                              Navigator.pop(context, true); // Close drawer
                              _goToElement(context, currentIndex1);
                            });
                          },
                        );
                      },
                      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                ExpansionTile(
                  controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
                  childrenPadding:
                      const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 20),
                  expandedCrossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  maintainState: true,
                  title: const Text(
                    'السور',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
                  ),
                  children: [
                    ListView.builder(
                      key: const PageStorageKey<String>("sora_list"),
                      controller: _scrollController2,
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      //physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                      itemCount: soraPages.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return ListTile(
                          title: Text(
                            style: const TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            'سورة: ${soraNames[index]}', // + 1}',
                          ),
                          tileColor: currentIndex2 == soraPages[index] - 1
                              ? Colors.deepPurple
                              : null,
                          onTap: () {
                            setState(() {
                              currentIndex2 = soraPages[index] - 1;
                              Navigator.pop(context, true); // Close drawer
                              _goToElement(context, currentIndex2);
                            });
                          },
                        );
                      },
                      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                ExpansionTile(
                  controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
                  childrenPadding:
                      const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 20),
                  expandedCrossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                  maintainState: true,
                  title: const Text(
                    'الصفحات',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 18.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                  children: [
                    ListView.builder(
                      key: const PageStorageKey<String>("pages_list"),
                      controller: _scrollController3,
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      //physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                      itemCount: 604,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return ListTile(
                          title: Text(
                            style: const TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            'الصفحة: ${index + 1}',
                          ),
                          tileColor:
                              currentIndex3 == index ? Colors.deepPurple : null,
                          onTap: () {
                            setState(() {
                              currentIndex3 = index;
                              Navigator.pop(context, true); // Close drawer
                              _goToElement(context, currentIndex3);
                            });
                          },
                        );
                      },
                      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                ExpansionTile(
                  controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
                  childrenPadding:
                      const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 20),
                  expandedCrossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                  maintainState: true,
                  title: const Text(
                    'العلامات',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 18.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                  children: [
                    ListView.builder(
                      key: const PageStorageKey<String>("pages_list"),
                      controller: _scrollController3,
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      //physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                      itemCount: bookmarkPages.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return ListTile(
                          title: Text(
                              style: const TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                              //bookmarks[index] == true
                              'الصفحة: ${bookmarkPages[index] + 1}'
                              //: '',
                              ),
                          tileColor:
                              currentIndex4 == index ? Colors.deepPurple : null,
                          onTap: () {
                            setState(() {
                              currentIndex4 = bookmarkPages[index];
                              Navigator.pop(context, true); // Close drawer
                              _goToElement(context, currentIndex4);
                            });
                          },
                        );
                      },
                      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  onchahged(int index) {
    setState(() {
      currentPage = index;
      //Saves the index of pageview.
      _saveIndex(index);
      _saveBookmarks(bookmarkPages);
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably crashing because you are using `async/await` in the `initState` thus the `build()` method is getting called before the `initState` is getting finished, and since you are using `currentPage` in the `build()` method, then it is telling you that it's still not initialized.

The best thing is just to give it and initial value of 0. Since in the `initState`, you are already doing that if there is no preference found.

```
int currentPage = 0;
```

or simply make it nullable:

```
int? currentPage;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I tried what you have said, but if I do that the app always starts at page one and the reader has to search for last page he reached last time.

Comment: Did you try just to make the currentpage nullable?

Comment: If it doesnt work, then try to add a FutureBuilder and in that, fetch the shared preference value and assign it to currentpage

Comment: Thank you Mr. Haddad for your valuable answers. Would you please give me a hint on how to add FutureBuilder, since I am newby.

Comment: I managed to solve the problem using FutureBuilder. But I am now faced with another error 'ScrollController not attached to any scroll views.'. I am using a function to enable the reader to jump to a specific page by calling 'pageViewController.jumpToPage(index);'. It was working fine before using FutureBuilder.

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52114535/scrollcontroller-not-attached-to-any-scroll-views

Comment: I managed to solve it using:
     SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
        pageViewController.jumpToPage(index);
      });
Thanks for directing me to that. My App looks great now.